# How to run custom HTTP Requests to one of my servers from a Wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I have a Wordpress Website with a Woocommerce product. When the product is purchased, I want to run a HTTP Request to one of my servers once the purchase is verified automatically.

The problem is I don't know if such code is executed through the web browser or the backend of the Wordpress site. If it is the former, then the API Key would be exposed and that I do not want.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are looking for is **Woocommerce Webhooks**. If you are not familiar with webhooks - they are HTTP events that happens on a custom event. That custom event can be: `order status changed`, `product updated`, `product deleted`, `customer created` and etc.

In other words (and to answer your questions about who sends the request), **your server** is responsible for sending the HTTP request to the **Delivery URL** of your choice. The URL of your choice should expect a **POST** request.

To learn more about how webhooks work in detail, you can visit the official [WooCommerce documentation](https://woo.com/document/webhooks/).

To give you guidelines, here are the steps you need to take in order to utilise webhooks in order to solve your problem:

1. Create a Webhook event from the Wordpress dashboard by navigating: **WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Webhooks**
2. Choose Webhook name, **Webhook topic** (on which event this webhook will be triggered), set Status to Active, and most importantly - set the Delivery URL to something like `www.yoursecondserver.com/webhooks/product-created`.
3. Your application on the [www.yoursecondserver.com](http://www.yoursecondserver.com) needs to have a **POST API endpoint** with a complete path of `www.yoursecondserver.com/webhooks/product-created`. The request body on this endpoint will have more information about the event that happend on your Woocommerce store. Eg: if you chose **Order Created** as a Webhook topic, then the payload will have information about the Order ID, Order total sum, Order line items, Customer details and etc.